# Cythonic Laplacian solving on a 3D regular grid

Tags: performance, numpy, cython

I have followed to official [Cython for NumPy users](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) to make a Laplacian solver on a 3D regular grid with Dirichlet conditions.

Right now I'm happy with the results it returns, but I'm wondering if there was a more efficient way to code this, especially since the tutorial I have followed is about 10 years old. I have very limited knowledge of C and I'm not sure if the data types (`ctypedef`) are properly chosen here and/or would have a significant impact on performance. I have tried types my indexes variables as `unsigned int` in different ways but I ended up giving up as I'm not really sure if it is relevant.

Also, I'm happy with any general coding style and good practices advice.

The Python code that calls my Cython function is inside a class and looks like this:

```
def _solve_laplacian(self):
    init = np.zeros_like(self.domain, float)
    init[np.logical_not(self.border)] = 1
    log.info("Solving Laplacian...")
    laplace_grid, iterations, max_error = laplace_solver(
        self.domain_idx_i,
        self.domain_idx_j,
        self.domain_idx_k,
        init,
        self.laplace_tolerance,
        self.laplace_max_iter,
        self.spacing)
    log.debug(
        f"Laplacian: {iterations} iterations, max_error = {max_error}")
    self.cropped_laplace_grid = laplace_grid
    self.laplacian_iterations = iterations
    self.laplacian_max_error = max_error
```

and here is the actual cython function:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_FLOAT
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_INT


# dirty fix to get rid of annoying warnings
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def solve_3D(np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_i,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_j,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_k,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=3] init,
             DTYPE_FLOAT tolerance,
             DTYPE_INT max_iterations,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=1] spacing):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=3] laplace_grid = np.copy(init)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=3] prev_laplace_grid = np.copy(
        laplace_grid)
    cdef DTYPE_INT iteration = 0
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT max_error = 1.0
    cdef DTYPE_INT n_points = len(domain_idx_i)
    cdef DTYPE_INT i, j, k, n
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT error
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT value
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT hi, hj, hk, hi2, hj2, hk2, factor

    hi, hj, hk = spacing
    hi2, hj2, hk2 = spacing ** 2

    factor = (hi2 * hj2 * hk2) / (2 * (hi2 * hj2 + hi2 * hk2 + hj2 * hk2))

    while max_error > tolerance and iteration < max_iterations:
        iteration += 1
        prev_laplace_grid[:] = laplace_grid
        for n in range(n_points):
            i = domain_idx_i[n]
            j = domain_idx_j[n]
            k = domain_idx_k[n]
            value = \
                (
                    (laplace_grid[i + 1, j, k] +
                     laplace_grid[i - 1, j, k]) / hi2 +
                    (laplace_grid[i, j + 1, k] +
                     laplace_grid[i, j - 1, k]) / hj2 +
                    (laplace_grid[i, j, k - 1] +
                     laplace_grid[i, j, k + 1]) / hk2
                ) * factor
            laplace_grid[i, j, k] = value
        max_error = np.nanmax(
            np.abs(
                (prev_laplace_grid[domain_idx_i, domain_idx_j, domain_idx_k] -
                 laplace_grid[domain_idx_i, domain_idx_j, domain_idx_k]) /
                prev_laplace_grid[domain_idx_i, domain_idx_j, domain_idx_k]))
    return laplace_grid, iteration, max_error
```

If you're interested in the complete Python package this is part of, it is [available here](https://gitlab.inria.fr/ncedilni/pyezzi) and is quite ugly right now. I'm trying to improve it so I'm not ashamed of it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was helped on the `#scipy` IRC channel by user [@ngoldbaum](https://stackexchange.com/users/1471365/ngoldbaum) and could substantially speed up my code by:

1. Avoiding to use any `numpy` methods in the main loop
2. Using OpenMP parallelization
3. Using true C division as there is no risk of division by zero
4. Avoiding to store the whole previous iteration values

…and some other minor stuff.

Here's what my solver looks like now:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.math cimport fabs

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_FLOAT
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_INT

# dirty fix to get rid of annoying warnings
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef bint has_converged(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=1] errors,
                        DTYPE_INT n,
                        DTYPE_FLOAT tolerance):
    cdef bint res = True
    cdef DTYPE_INT i
    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):  # is prange useful here ?
        if errors[i] > tolerance:
            res = False
            break
    return res

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def solve_3D(np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_i,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_j,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT, ndim=1] domain_idx_k,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=3] init,
             DTYPE_FLOAT tolerance,
             DTYPE_INT max_iterations,
             np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=1] spacing):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=3] laplace_grid = np.copy(init)
    cdef DTYPE_INT iteration = 0
    cdef DTYPE_INT n_points = len(domain_idx_i)
    cdef DTYPE_INT i, j, k, n
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT value
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT hi, hj, hk, hi2, hj2, hk2, factor, prev_value
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT, ndim=1] errors = np.zeros(n_points,
                                                           np.float64)
    cdef bint convergence = False

    hi, hj, hk = spacing
    hi2, hj2, hk2 = spacing ** 2

    factor = (hi2 * hj2 * hk2) / (2 * (hi2 * hj2 + hi2 * hk2 + hj2 * hk2))

    while not convergence and iteration < max_iterations:
        iteration += 1
        for n in prange(n_points, nogil=True):
            i = domain_idx_i[n]
            j = domain_idx_j[n]
            k = domain_idx_k[n]
            value = ((laplace_grid[i + 1, j, k] +
                      laplace_grid[i - 1, j, k]) / hi2 +
                     (laplace_grid[i, j + 1, k] +
                      laplace_grid[i, j - 1, k]) / hj2 +
                     (laplace_grid[i, j, k - 1] +
                      laplace_grid[i, j, k + 1]) / hk2) * factor
            prev_value = laplace_grid[i, j, k]
            laplace_grid[i, j, k] = value
            errors[n] = fabs((prev_value - value) / prev_value)

        if iteration == 1:
            convergence = False
        else:
            convergence = has_converged(errors, n, tolerance)

    return laplace_grid, iteration, np.nanmax(errors)
```

I think it could be a bit better if `errors` were checked "on the fly", removing the second `for` loop every `while` iteration. However, I did not find out to do that efficiently in a multithread `prange`… maybe it's not worth it!